# How to move jquery function/callback into document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change this code so that I can add it to the standard document ready for jquery so that all my scripts are together.

```
 /*
 * Fetch RSS feed once page has finished loading.
 */
(function(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data.responseData.feed);
        }
    });
})('http://www.bet365.com/news/en/betting/sports/rss', function(feed){
    var entries = feed.entries, content, publishDate;
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        publishDate = new Date(entries[i].publishedDate);
        date = publishDate.getDate() + '/' + publishDate.getMonth() + '/' + publishDate.getFullYear();
        content = truncateText((entries[i].contentSnippet) ? entries[i].contentSnippet : entries[i].content, 100);
        jQuery('#rss > ul').append('<li><a href="' + entries[i].link + '" title=" ' + content + ' " target="_blank"><span> ' + date + '</span>' + entries[i].title + '</a></li>');
    }
});
```

Comment: $(function () { /*All the above code in here*/ } );

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from adding this code to your .ready code. Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to do by putting it there? Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

separate the functions.. it will good to use and understand

```
var my_callback = function(feed){ // Change to desired URL
    var entries = feed.entries, content, publishDate;
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        publishDate = new Date(entries[i].publishedDate);
        date = publishDate.getDate() + '/' + publishDate.getMonth() + '/' + publishDate.getFullYear();
        content = truncateText((entries[i].contentSnippet) ? entries[i].contentSnippet : entries[i].content, 100);
        jQuery('#rss > ul').append('<li><a href="' + entries[i].link + '" title=" ' + content + ' " target="_blank"><span> ' + date + '</span>' + entries[i].title + '</a></li>');
    }

function make_ajax_call(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data.responseData.feed);
        }
    });
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  make_ajax_call('http://www.bet365.com/news/en/betting/sports/rss',my_callback);
});
```

Comment: This separation will also pollute global namespace with some functions which may not be so good. Sure it ay be aceptable in many cases...

Comment: very nice, thank you for sharing that insight of keeping one function to load the data, and another function to do all the manipulations of the data.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it with:

```
$(function(){
  // Your code here
});
```

Actually `$` is an alias for `$.ready` (and it's the same as `$(document).ready`) if function is passed as argument